# Remove decimal points from numbers to use in a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am going to be matching up numbers to link between the tables.

The issue is one might be 1234567 and the other would be 1234.567

Is there anything I can do to eliminate the . so I can link the tables together and pull data?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Base on your logic, do you want 12340 match 12.34? how about 1234 v.s. 0.1234? Should it match too?

Comment: I would want the entire code including all 0's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to join the 2 tables on the common column as so:

```
select a.cola, b.colb 
from tablea a inner join tableb b 
on replace(b.commonfield,'.','')=replace(a.commonfield,'.','')
```

This will ensure that if either column has a `.`, it's removed and matched only by the numbers.

Comment: That will work if b.commonfield is a string so it may be necessary to cast the value as well:

Comment: @JeffBond no, replace will cast it to `varchar` automatically.

Comment: So I likely need to Cast the variables to strings remove the . and it should work?